# how to plot data which has mostly true values in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

On every row I  can either have 0 or 1.
If my data is like this

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I want `plot 0:1` such that the graph should appear like a red block,
when I use `line` I dont see anything, since probably all values are touching the ceiling of graph.

Which graph type should i use to visualise such a graph in gnuplot?

another e.g

```
1
1
1
0
1
1
```

should appear like two red blocks separate by one thin white line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid auto-range when your data is very range-limited, you can explicitly set the yrange or give it as an argument to `plot`.

The best I can come up with to get blocky plots is to use `boxes`. Something like this might do:

```
set boxwidth 1.8          
plot [] [0:1.1] 'in2' using 0:1 with boxes fs solid .5 noborder
```